# Структура С, нарушение прав доступа при записи

Tags: c, строки, структуры

При добавлении имени пишет, нарушение прав доступа при записи, а при добавлении телефона не работает иф, пишет введите номер, хотя ввожу его правильно

```
struct TB  
{  
    char name[11];   
    char surname[21];   
    char number[13];  
    bool flag;  
}list[20];  

   void add(TB*zapis)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i<20; ++i)  
    {  
        if (zapis[i].flag == false)  
        {  
            char number[13];  
            printf("Vvedite imja: \n");  
            scanf_s("%s", zapis[i].name);  
            while (strlen(zapis[i].name)>10)  
            {  
                printf("error!Vvedite povtorno \n");  
                scanf_s("%s", &zapis[i].name);  
            }  
            printf("Vvedite familiju: \n");  
            scanf_s("%s", &zapis[i].surname);  
            while (strlen(zapis[i].surname)>20)  
            {  
                printf("error!Vvedite povtorno \n");  
                scanf_s("%s", &zapis[i].surname);  
            }  

            printf("Vvedite nomer telephona: \n");
            scanf_s("%s", &number);

            while (strlen(number)>12)
            {
                printf("error!vvedite povtorno \n");
                scanf_s("%s", &number);


            }
            for (int j = 0; j<12; ++j)
            {


                if (isdigit(number[j]) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Don't type number like this!vvedite nomer! \n");
                    scanf_s("%s", &number);

                }

            }
            for (int j = 0; j<20; ++j)
            {
                if (strcmp(number, zapis[j].number) == 0 && (zapis[j].flag == true))
                {
                    printf("Takoyi nomer est' \n");
                    return;

                }
                else
                    strcpy_s(zapis[i].number, number);

            }
            zapis[i].flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Your register sucessfully added! \n");
    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если это вижуал студия, тогда и ответ @zenden2k также не совсем правильный.  Согласно документации, [scanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w40768et.aspx) будет иметь ещё один параметр - фактический размер буфера. Итого, правильно так

```
scanf_s("%s", number, 13);
```

или даже лучше так

```
scanf_s("%s", number, _countof(number));
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка о нарушении прав доступа не появляется, но по-прежнему не работает иф, я ввожу правильный номер, а мне пишет, что он неправильый

Comment: Вполне возможно, что номер "неверный". Например, в номере есть лишний пробел или нулевой символ.
отладка, отладка и ещё раз отладка.

Comment: я не умею ею пользоваться:(

Comment: не умеете пользоватся отладчиком - пользуйтесь отладочным выводом. То есть, в нужных местах печатайте значения переменных и сравнивайте с ожидаемым. Например, перед if распечатайте все переменные, которые в нем учавствуют. Это даст возможность сделать сравнение "ручками". В том случае, если ничего не вывелось, значит к этой строке исполнение даже не дошло.

Comment: Поменяла в форе 12 на strlen(number) вроде работает

Comment: У меня не работает strlen, ввожу имя больше 10 символов и не предлагает ввести еще раз, ввод фамилии опускается и предлагает ввести сразу номер

Comment: Логично. Строка то под 10 символов. В scant_s больше не прочитает. Остаток вычитывает следующий scanf

Comment: а как мне сделать так, чтобы, сели пользователь ввел больше 10 символов ему предложило еще раз ввести?                                                                                do  
   {
    printf("Vvedite imja: \n");
    
    scanf_s("%s", zapis[i].name, _countof(zapis[i].name));
    len = strlen(zapis[i].name);
    printf("%d",len);
   } while (len == 0);

Comment: я бы сделал по простому - массивы для ввода имени-фамилии сделал бы побольше (символов 250-300).  Потом проверял длину введенных данных. Если они больше нужного - просто просил ввесли ещё раз или обрезал.
Конечно, если пользователь введет больше 250 символов - будут те же проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно используете scanf. Надо так:

```
scanf_s("%s", zapis[i].name);
scanf_s("%s", number);
```

т.е. без амперсанда для строк

Comment: Я исправила, но ошибка не исчезла

Comment: Вы бы прошлись под отладчиком и сказали нам, какая именно строчка вылетает.

Comment: Ввела правильный номер(все цифры), сработал иф и предложил ввести другой номер, ввела номер с буквами вылетело окно debug assertion failed c>=-1 && c<=255