# Ошибка при вводе. Структуры C++

Tags: c++

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF86C6A8028 (ucrtbase.dll) в Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x00007FF6178C1A06.

Меняю спецификаторы в `scanf` `%s` например на `%i` перестает выходить эта ошибка, но смысл естественно теряется.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>

#define ARR_SIZE 2

typedef struct HUM_RES_DEP
{
    char Position[20];
    char SecName[15];
    char Init[2];
    int Year;
    int WorkExp;
    int Salary;
}HUM_RUS_DEP;

void BubleSort(HUM_RES_DEP *arr);
void InPut(HUM_RES_DEP *arr);
void OutPut(HUM_RES_DEP *arr);


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    HUM_RES_DEP arr[ARR_SIZE];
    InPut(arr);
    BubleSort(arr);
    OutPut(arr);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void BubleSort(HUM_RES_DEP *arr)
{
    HUM_RES_DEP temp;
    for (int i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<(ARR_SIZE - 1); j++){
            if (arr[j].SecName>arr[j + 1].SecName){
                temp = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        };
    };
}
void InPut(HUM_RES_DEP *arr)
{
    printf("Введите данные:\n|  Должность   |  Фамилия  | Инициалы | Год рождения | Стаж работы, мес |  Оклад |\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++){
        scanf_s("%s %s %s %d %d %d", &arr[i].Position, &arr[i].SecName, &arr[i].Init, &arr[i].Year, &arr[i].WorkExp, &arr[i].Salary);
    };
}

void OutPut(HUM_RES_DEP *arr)
{
    printf("   __________________________________________________________________________________________");
    printf("\n|                                       Отдел Кадров                                       |");
    printf("\n|__________________________________________________________________________________________|");
    printf("\n|  Должность   |   Фамилия   |  Инициалы   | Год рождения |  Стаж работы, мес  |   Оклад   |");
    printf("\n|______________|_____________|_____________|______________|____________________|___________|");
    for (int i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++){
        printf("\n|%10s| %10s| %10s| %10d| %10d| %10d|", arr[i].Position, arr[i].SecName, arr[i].Init, arr[i].Year, arr[i].WorkExp, arr[i].Salary);
        printf("\n|______________|_____________|_____________|_____________|_____________________|___________|");
    };
}
```

Comment: При чтении строк `scanf_s` используется не как обычный `scanf`. Либо замените `scanf_s` на `scanf`, либо читайте мануал к `scanf_s`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat При замене 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. выдает

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450423/how-to-use-crt-secure-no-warnings

Comment: Использование оператора `&` при формате `%s` в `scanf` (или `scanf_s`) - практически всегда ошибка.

Comment: Если вам компилятор посоветовал использовать `scanf_s`, это совсем не означает, что достаточно просто исправить `scanf` на `scanf_s` и все.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415800/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%A1-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В отличие от scanf и wscanf, scanf_s и wscanf_s требуют указания
>   размеров буфера для некоторых параметров. Указать размеры для всех c,
>   C, s, S, или строка, набор элементов управления [] параметры. Размер
>   буфера в символах передается как дополнительный параметр.
>   Непосредственно за указатель на буфер или переменную. Например если вы
>   читаете строку, размер буфера для этой строки передается следующим
>   образом:

```
char s[10];
scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9
```

Пользуйтесь простым `scanf`.

Comment: Замена scanf'а помогла, спасибо